# Can Google Places API take a live text input and generate an address/place as the user is typing (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm mainly wondering about how robust the Google Places API is, and whether it can be used to scan a text input in real-time (possibly even auto-completing it) and parse a location from that input.

And is there a way to do that without making multiple API calls on a single text input?

[This](https://magical.app) might help with visualizing what we're trying to build out. It may be easier to parse the remaining portion of the text input after other parts of the text (date/time, title) would be tagged and removed from scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Got it: so according to the Places Autocomplete component of Places API:

> The Place Autocomplete service can match on full words as well as
>   substrings. Applications can therefore send queries as the user types,
>   to provide on-the-fly place predictions.